# How to use system commands in lua

Tags: ubuntu, lua, lua-table

I tried to print the values through running the commands "ip -4 route show".
Acturally running by command it is giving 3 values. But while trying through programming, the iteration is running for first 2 times. for 3rd iteration which returning nil.

while running in command line:

```
root@start:/usr/lib/lua/transformer/mapper# ip -4 route show
169.254.1.0/24 dev vlan_lte_mgmt  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.1.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev br-lan  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1 
239.0.0.0/8 dev br-lan  scope link
```

While trying through program, the iteration is working for 2 times only. the last iteration is reurning nil value.

```
function M.loadRoutes(onlyDefault)                                                                                                                     
  local routes = {}                                                                                                                                    
  local defaultRoute                                                                                                                                   
  local i, t, popen = 0, {}, io.popen                                                                                                                  
  local fd = popen("ip -4 route show")                                                                                                                 
  if fd then 
    for line in fd:lines() do                                                                                                                          
        local fields = {}                                                                                                                              
        fields.destip,fields.ifname,fields.gateway = line:match("(%S+)%s+%S+%s+(%S+)%s+%S+%s+%S+%s+%S+%s+%S+%s+%S+%s+(%S)")
```

please help me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because last line not don't match with pattern.

Answer (score 0):

As FareakyGnome says, your pattern is searching for a line with 9 non-space "words" but the last line in your output only has 5 non-space words. The pattern doesn't match, so `line:match(...)` returns nil, and all three variables being assigned will get assigned nil.

You will probably need to change how you're trying to match the lines in order to make this work. Maybe try matching for the first two variables in one match and the third in a separate match:

```
fields.destip, fields.ifname = line:match( "(%S+)%s+%S+%s+(%S+)" )
fields.gateway = line:match( "%S+%s+%S+%s+%S+%s+%S+%s+%S+%s+%S+%s+%S+%s+%S+%s+(%S)" )
```

Then the first two variables should get filled, and the third will be filled if there are enough non-space words, or else remain nil, indicating that that field wasn't available in the output.